# This form template is not currently browser-enabled. It must either be republished as a browser-enabled form,

Tags: document-library, forms-services

I have the following error when accessing a web-based InfoPath form.

`This form template is not currently browser-enabled. It must either be republished as a browser-enabled form, or opened using Microsoft Office InfoPath 2007.`

I have ensure that the form is able to open in a web browser and also check that the document library is also set to 'Display as a Webpage' but it seems that I could not get it open on the web browser.

Please enlighten me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into this MSDN forum link :- [Solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointinfopath/thread/c9617953-a54c-44ec-86cf-df215c750c18/)

If the above doesnt work , try for the hotfix as provied here [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939593)